# How to grab the width attribute of an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a graph using html, now I want to give it a nice effect when it initially loads. I want the bars of the graph to fly in from the left. The code below does that, only problem is each bar ends up with 70% width (obviously since I set that in the jQuery code). Instead I need that number to be unique to the width set within the bars (span tags). I assume the answer would be something like:

```
$(this).attr('width')...
```

but I can't get it to work, please help.

The Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

div.graph { display: none; border: 1px solid red; height: 200px; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }

div.graph span { display: none; display: block; background: red; height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.graph').fadeIn('slow');

    $('div.graph > span').animate({
        width: "70%"
    }, 1500 );

});
</script>

<div class="graph">
    <span style='width:10%'></span>
    <span style='width:40%'></span>
    <span style='width:25%'></span>
    <span style='width:15%'></span>
    <span style='width:10%'></span>
</div><!-- graph -->
```

Comment: Can you not use `$(this).width()` ?  Nevermind that, in my suggestion "this" is the window, and therefore the window's width.

Comment: @Jon ha, no wonder when I tried that the bars got real huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
$('div.graph > span').each(function(){
    var w=$(this).width();
    $(this).width(0);
    $(this).animate({
        width: w
    }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: you should really save $(this) to a variable or it has to do the lookup every time, its just a goos habit to get into. See my answer.

Comment: well actually the best way to do it would be $(this).width(0).animate();

Comment: since everyone seems to be selling himself here, for more elegant solution you can check out my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

**edit**
After reading your code, if you don't care for non-JS support [there are many casex when you don't], you can use `.data()` method [very elegant, too :)]

HTML:

```
<span data-width="10%">Hello</span>
```

JS:

```
$('div.graph > span').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).data('width')
    }, 1500 );
});
```

**updated example**

http://jsfiddle.net/vGUM7/2/

**code**

```
.animate({
  'width': $(element).width()
 },500);
```

**example**

http://jsfiddle.net/vGUM7/1/

[updated with %]

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.graph > span').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var w = $this.width();  // Grab what it should be
        $this.width(0);  // Reset so it does the animation
        $this.animate({
            width: w
        }, 1500 );
    });
    $('div.graph').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

It reads what you want the bar to be, then sets it back to 0. setting up the animation to go. After its all set, the fade in starts

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     $('div.graph').fadeIn('slow');

     var bars = $('div.graph > span');
     for(var i=0; i<bars.length; i++){
       var w = $(bars[i]).width();
       $(bars[i]).width(0);
       $(bars[i]).animate({
          width: w
       }, 1500);
     }
```

Comment: jQuery has the .each() method for things like this.

Answer (score -1):

`$(this).width()` should work, or else `$(this).css('width');`

however `.css('width')` will return the value that the css has, so could be '10%' for example or 'auto'

Comment: yeah but another problem is I can't use any of that within the animate function's acceptable parameters.

Comment: create as a variable, and use the variable instead.